# Evaluating $\sum_{i=2}^7\,2^{i+2}$

Tags: summation

I am going through my textbook and have come across this question that asks to work out the sigma, this sigma is troubling me, I am not understanding how to do the "to the power of I + 2" part. Any help would be great, thanks.
$$\sum_{i=2}^7\,2^{i+2}$$

Comment: Do you mean:  $\sum_{i=2}^7\,2^{i+2}$?

Comment: Yes that's correct lulu, i was only wording it the same way as the textbook has.

Comment: Well, what's the problem?  It's only six terms ...you could do it by hand.  The usual trick would be to multiply it by $2$ and compare the two sums, but really it's not hard to just do it out.

Comment: $2^4 + 2^5 + 2^6 + 2^7 + 2^8 + 2^9 = 16 + 32 + 64 + 128 + 256 + 512 = 1023 - 31 = 992$

Comment: @YunusSyed, I think you meant to subtract $15$, not $31$.

Comment: yes, silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Observe that 
$$
\sum_{i=2}^72^{i+2}=\sum_{i=2}^72^i2^2=2^2\sum_{i=2}^72^i.
$$
What happens is just that the power is $2$ more than the current value of $i$.  Initially, $i=2$, so the power starts at $i+2=4$.  If you want to further reduce the sum, let $j=i-2$, then $i=j+2$ and
$$
2^2\sum_{i=2}^72^i=2^2\sum_{j=0}^52^{j+2}=2^2\sum_{j=0}^52^j2^2=2^4\sum_{j=0}^52^j.
$$
You can calculate this by hand or use the geometric sum formula at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Using $2^{x}=(2-1)2^{x}=2^{x+1}-2^{x}$. We are trying to find,

$$2^{2+2}+2^{3+2}+2^{4+2}+2^{5+2}+2^{6+2}+2^{7+2}$$

$$=2^{4}+2^{5}+2^{6}+2^{7}+2^{8}+2^{9}$$

$$=(\color{red}{2^{5}}-2^{4})+(\color{blue}{2^{6}}-\color{red}{2^{5}})+(\color{green}{2^{7}}-\color{blue}{2^{6}})+(\color{orange}{2^{8}}-\color{green}{2^{7}})+(\color{purple}{2^{9}}-\color{orange}{2^{8}})+(2^{10}-\color{purple}{2^{9}})$$

Everything cancels except for,

$$-2^{4}+2^{10}$$

$$=1008$$

Answer (score 0):

Um... just do it

$\sum_{i=2}^7 2^{i+2} = 2^{2+2} + 2^{3+2} + 2^{4+2} + .... + 2^{7+2}$

... or were you not supposed to do it directly and figure a formula.

$b^{i+2}= b^ib^2$

So $\sum_{i=2}2^{i+2} = \sum_{i=2}^72^i*4 = 4\sum_{i=2}^7 2^i$  Can you figure out what $\sum_{i=2}^7 2^i$ is?

Did you know that $\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i  = 2^{k-1} -1$?  If you didn't can you figure out why $1 +2 +4 + 8 + ....... + 2^{k-1} = 2^k - 1$?

Knowing that... $\sum_{i = 2}^7 2^i$ suppose your replace all the $i$ with $j = i-2$ so $i = j+2$.  $\sum_{i=2;j = 2-2=0}^{7-2=5} 2^{j+2}=\sum_{j=0}^5 2^22^j$.  Can you figure that out?